# What does the | smtp | bit mean on the following Ruby snippet?

Tags: ruby

I'm using MailFactory to send an email, and encountered this strange clause I've not seen before. I'm from PHP, and been doing Ruby now for about a week and a half.

Is the | smtp | variable a value that gets returned by Net::SMTP.start, and then utilised in the {} block?

```
response = Net::SMTP.start(cfg['host'], 25, cfg['from_domain'], cfg['username'], cfg['password'], :plain) {
    | smtp |
    recipients = cfg['mail_targets']['errors']
    smtp.send_message(mail.to_s, mail.from, [recipients, mail])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a block.

Net::SMTP::start: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html#method-c-start

More about ruby blocks: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BlocksInRuby

Answer (score 1):

It's the argument passed from `start` into the block.

> When this methods is called with a block, the newly-started SMTP object is yielded to the block, and automatically closed after the block call finishes. Otherwise, it is the caller’s responsibility to close the session when finished.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/SMTP

Answer (score 1):

`smtp` is the name of the argument passed into the block. the `{ |smtp| <code> }` syntax is Ruby block syntax.

http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/simpleRuby.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the formatting is a little odd (usually the block variables are next to the '{') but you're working with a Net::SMTP instance inside the block.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html